# CFG to PDA (Context free grammar to Push Down Automata)

Tags: grammar, pushdown-automaton

How can I convert the next CFG to a PDA?

```
S-> abScB | e

B-> bB | b
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first look at the language the CFG is generating. It's a pretty complex language actually. With only one expansion of S it'll be `abc(b(b*))`. For two, you'll get `ab[abc(b(b*))]c(b(b*))`, three will be `ab[ab[abc(b(b*))]c(b(b*))]c(b(b*))` and so on. I've put in square braces the part that's added from the S transition. This language appears to be `{(ab)^n (c(b(b^x_i)))^m}` where `x_i` is an integer greater than or equal to 0, and each `x_1, x_2, ... , x_i` can be different. *n* and *m* are both integers greater than or equal to 0.

To convert to a PDA, we can start with the easy parts. Your alphabet is {a,b,c}, you'll need a state for the "ab" section, and one for the "c(b(b^x_i)" part. Let's call the first one state *p* and the second *q*. Your stack alphabet will be {bottom,A,C}. Bottom is simply the symbol that indicates we've reached the bottom of the stack. Now the hard part, the delta transitions, assuming acceptance by empty stack:

```
(p,e,bottom),(p,e) - this is for "m" = 0, accepting the empty string "e" or the case (ab)^n (this is an accepting state)
(p,a,bottom),(p, A bottom) - if we read an "a" and the stack is empty, push an A to the stack
(p,b,A),(p,e) - if we get a "b" and there was already an A on the stack, remove it
(p,c,bottom),(q,C bottom) - if we get a "c" and the stack was empty (i.e. we've finished the (ab)^n section), go to state q and push a C onto the stack
(q,b,C),(q,e) - if we get a "b" after a c, remove the C from the stack
(q,b,bottom),(q,bottom) - if we get a "b" in the b^x_i section, pop then immediately push bottom onto the stack
(q,c,bottom),(q,C bottom) - if we get a "c" after the b^x_i section, push a C onto the stack
(q,e,bottom),(q,e) - if we finish our string and our stack is empty (as it should be), then this is an accepting state
```

The above transitions that read an empty string and produce an empty stack are the accepting states. All the transitions that aren't allowed (e.g. getting a "c" when there's already a C on the stack) are not included.

Hope that helps!